# Como comparar hora sistema contra una hora establecida

Tags: java, android

Necesito comparar una hora establecida contra la hora del sistema,pero me salta al mensaje "no hay nada",por favor ayúdenme a determinar que me hace falta para que al final me salga el mensaje "hola" cuando sea esa hora en el sistema .

Este es el código :

```
package jaxper.comparacion;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    public  String getHora(String strFormato) {

        Calendar objCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(strFormato);

        String strHora = simpleDateFormat.format(objCalendar.getTime());
        return strHora;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        startAlert();

    }   public void startAlert() {


        String hora_sistema = getHora("HH:mm"); //hora sistema
        String mihora = "23:57"; //hora establecida

        int timeInSec = 5;

        if ( mihora.equals(hora_sistema )){


            Toast.makeText(this, " hola ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }else {Toast.makeText(this, "no hay nada ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
    }
}
```

Comment: Cuando entras al if, ¿que tienes en hora_sistema? Tienes que asegurarte que tienes algún valor con el mismo formato que guardas en mi_hora porque la comparación está bien hecha

Comment: como hago para que guarde la hora actual en hora_sistema y en que formato lo debo poner?

Comment: No digo que lo hagas mal o qe tengas que cambiar la forma de hacerlo, lo que quiero es saber qué te guarda en hora_sistema para ver si la función getHora te hace lo que quieres que haga

Comment: la verdad soy muy nuevo en esto,como hago para mirar que valor guarda en hora_sistema ? ya que creia que asi como tengo este codigo me iba a tomar la hora del sistema, pero al parecer no ,porque inmediamente se salta a else.

Comment: Puedes mostrarla en un Toast por ejemplo. Asegúrate que el emulador donde pruebas esto está en hora

Comment: Listo,me sale la hora actual "02:46",no entiendo porque no hace la comparación.

Comment: utilizo un dispositivo fisico y tiene la hora actualizada

Comment: Pablo Simon DiEstefano muchas gracias,por medio del debuggeo me di cuenta que el formato de la hora tenia dos puntos mas y ya me funciona.

Comment: Me alegro =), ánimo!

Answer (score 0):

En realidad tu código es correcto,

```
public  String getHora(String strFormato) {

    Calendar objCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(strFormato);
    String strHora = simpleDateFormat.format(objCalendar.getTime());
    return strHora;

}
```

el formato también, de hecho se obtiene un formato "00:00" ("HH:mm").

Solo tienes que asegurar que la llamada del método para obtener la hora (`getHora()` ) se realice en realidad a la hora que establece la comparación.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si la hora es igual entonces se mostraría el `Toast` con el mensaje "hola".